# Reprojecting a polygon did not change the shape

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am trying to figure out what the reason is that when reprojecting my data the position and shape of my polygon does not change.

Steps I took

- On the basemap (ESRI satellite) I drew a polygon (WGS84 4326) as CRS.
- Then I reprojected this polygon to multiple random other CRS

The weird thing is that every time I reproject the polygon is shown on exactly the same location and with the same shape as the the one I made initially.

Comment: I guess that you have used the same CRS for you QGIS project all the time, and because QGIS does on-the-fly re-projection the data looks the same on your screen. Change the project CRS into the CRS of your data and you should see the difference.

Comment: So, your telling QGIS to translate the position of a feature from one "language" to another. Why would the position change, when you only change the language?

Comment: @Erik I thought that each projection has its own way of projecting the data, so if I change the projection of my data I assumed that it would look different.

Comment: You assumed wrong.

Comment: Your data will look different if you change the CRS of the project. Test with EPSG:4326 and EPSG:3857. Or check the option "No CRS (or unknown/non-Earth projection", then QGIS should show your data "raw" that probably meets your assumption.

Comment: @Erik each CRS has its own disformations right? This is the reason that some countries look differently in different CRS. Now when I draw a polygon in a certain CRS and the reproject, the ''language'' changes as user30184 calls it, but the locations on the map where the polygon is located should also change. Could you tell me where my thinking is wrong.

Comment: You forgot to reckon with the "universal translator" that is the map display. All you're doing is changing the display speed (slower), because it has to convert the shapes back to the display projection when  actually drawn.  If you started a new map with each new dataset, then the data would look different, because the map canvas would use that first CRS as the display CRS.

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/coordinate_reference_systems.html?highlight=fly#on-the-fly-projection

Comment: The relative location will not change: a polygon drawn around your town in projection A will remain a polygon around your town in projection B. The shape of said polygon can change (ex: a circle in 4326 will look like an ellipse in 3857), but this is only a visual artifact. You are right that some projections preserve true angles, others preserve distances, others preserve areas, others preserves nothing (etc), but the location of a geometry with respect to other ones will not change.

Comment: @JGH this is again a very valuable additional answer and really clears things up. Is it then also correct that the result of an area calculation will always be the same even though the shape changes due to different projections?

Comment: Certainly not! Some projection can be used for area calculation, others should be avoided at all cost

Comment: @JGH but if the projection is only a visual effect (which I understand because it does not change the actual coordinates but only the way they are drawn) then you would expect the final area to be the same right?

Comment: no, distance/angle/area computation will use the geometry as it is, including its distortion.

Comment: @JGH thank you very much for this.